# Bash: how to create multiple folder with names ending from elements from an array

Tags: bash

I created an array in bash by `arr=($(seq 0.75 0.01 1))` . Problem is I want to create multiple folders with names like this, "folder0.75 , folder0.76,... folder1" . I tried `mkdir folder${arr}` but it does not give me what I want.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the array?

Comment: How do I do that ? Does it mean I need to write a bash script ? Or it can still be done on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in ${arr[@]}; do 
  mkdir "folder${i}"
done
```

or with bash's Parameter Expansion:

```
mkdir "${arr[@]/#/folder}"
```

Comment: `mkdir "{arr[@]}"` looks really elegant but how do I concatenate "folder" in front of ${arr[@]} . Also , I want to know what is difference between using single quote and double quote in this case ?

Comment: I've fixed my answer. To your question, please take a look at: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
for item in $(cmd); do
  mkdir "$item";
done
```